# readxl memory leak in R on Linux RStudio Server

Tags: r, dataframe

I was working on something relatively simple: I have three files that weigh ~150MB each, about 240k rows and 145 columns each, and wanted to join them. The thing is, when I open the first file with `readxl::read_excel`, it suddenly requires 10GB of memory just to open the file, making it impossible for me to open the three files  (was barely able to open the first one after several tries and reinstalling `readxl`), even though when this file is read, the dataframe object weighs 287MB as per `object_size()`.

I'm a bit baffled as to why R is needing so much RAM to open my file. Any ideas on what could be happening? Something I might be missing? Any less memory intensive alternatives?

As extra information, when I opened the file I saw it has filters enabled and some table formatting from Excel.

Thank you very much

Comment: If the file is publicly available, it would help reproducibility of this issue.

Comment: If you are able to open the file in excel then try saving it as a csv and read that instead

Comment: The file isn't publicly available nor I can modify it as of now, as it is hosted in the server and depends on the IT team